# SAM R21 bootloader waits for clock infinitely

Tags: arduino, bootloader, cortex-m, atmelstudio

I'm working on a project and I need to make Arduino IDE communicate with the SAM R21 XPRO so I can program it like a normal Arduino board. 
I started from the arduino bootloader for mzero which is like a D21 and wanted to modify it to suit my needs but I stumbled into an infinite loop.

When starting the usb, the program waits infinitely for the clock to start.

```
/* Check clock after enable module, request the clock */
udd_wait_clock_ready();
```

Inside that function the program hangs at the **first while**

```
#define DFLL_READY_FLAG (SYSCTRL_PCLKSR_DFLLRDY | \
                         SYSCTRL_PCLKSR_DFLLLCKF | SYSCTRL_PCLKSR_DFLLLCKC)

/* In USB recovery mode the status is not checked */
if (!(SYSCTRL->DFLLCTRL.reg & SYSCTRL_DFLLCTRL_USBCRM)) {
    while((SYSCTRL->PCLKSR.reg & DFLL_READY_FLAG) != DFLL_READY_FLAG);
} else {
    while((SYSCTRL->PCLKSR.reg & SYSCTRL_PCLKSR_DFLLRDY) != SYSCTRL_PCLKSR_DFLLRDY);
}
```

I've been reading the datasheet for some time and the only thing that I encoutered is the following.

> 3 - The DFLL status bits in the PCLKSR register during the USB clock
>   recovery mode can be wrong after a USB suspend state.
>
> Fix/Workaround:
>   Do not monitor the DFLL status bits in the PCLKSR register during the USB clock
>   recovery mode.

I tried to take in account only the DFLLRDY flag, it doesn't stop there anymore, but after it returns to main and waits for messages, the USB raises the interrupt flag and it keeps reseting the board.

I also tried modifying the clock configs to start all the clock because I thought that maybe I forgot to turn them on, but no success, the DFLLLCKF and DFLLLCKC flags don't get set to 1.

R21 datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/SAM-R21_Datasheet.pdf

D21 bootloader: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-samd/tree/master/bootloaders/mzero/Bootloader_D21/src

My R21 project: https://github.com/BlanzeanuDoru/lucrare_licenta/tree/master/bootloader_r21/bootloader_r21/src

Some advice to what to do next would be very helpful. Thanks.